# Can i get profile information from twitter using any jar files?

Tags: android, twitter, jar, twitter4j

I am using a Twitter login in my application and once when a user logs in with his twitter id I need to retrieve the basic profile information from the twitter.

Is there any jar file to achieve that?

I did the same thing in `facebook` profile retrieval with the help of some JAR file and it is easier to integrate.

I also tried with `twitter4android` from twitter developer site for android but it is quite complicated. If there is any jar file as you know please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twitter4j jar file.
With the below code , you can get every detail about any user.

```
String[] srch = new String[] {"username1"."username2"};
            ResponseList<User> users = twitter.lookupUsers(srch);
            for (User user : users) 
            {
                System.out.println("idddddddddd " +user.getId() +  " " + user.getName());
                if (user.getStatus() != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(" Latest tweet @" + user.getScreenName() + " - " + user.getStatus().getText());
                    System.out.println("timeline");
                    List<Status> statusess = twitter.getFriendsTimeline();


                    System.out.println("Showing @" + user.getScreenName() + "'s friends timeline.");
                    for (Status status3 : statusess) 
                    {


                    System.out.println("@" + status3.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status3.getText());
                          System.out.println("Favourites Count" + user.getFavouritesCount());
                           System.out.println( "Friends Count"  + user.getFriendsCount());
                           System.out.println("Name "  + user.getName());
                           System.out.println("Description" + user.getDescription());
                           System.out.println("URL" + user.getId());
                           System.out.println("Followerrs" + user.getFollowersCount());
                           System.out.println("Profile image URL "  + user.getProfileImageUrlHttps()); 


                    }


                     /* 

                       */
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter4J may meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 very good Twitter Java libraries listed on the official Twitter developer website. 
[Twitter Java Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#java)